# Программно вставить View-элемент между двумя другими

Tags: android, android-studio, view, textview, imageview

К примеру, имеется фрагмент с такой разметкой

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Как программным способом вставить между двумя TextView, к примеру, ImageView?

Comment: Если известно какие вью и сколько их будет добавлено, можно заранее разместить их в разметке, и программно сделать их не видимыми задав view.setVisibility(View.GONE)  и там где нужно менять состояние на видимые

Comment: @McDaggen думал об этом, но в зависимости от данных у меня будет расположен либо imageview, либо videoveiw, поэтому данным способом придется накладывать один вью на другой, что будет не совсем удобно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `addView(View child, int index)`,  где `child` - Ваш ImageView, а `index` - позиция, в которую будет добавлен Ваш дочерний элемент.

[addView (View child, int index)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20int))